# The nice sliding, multilayer Ubuntu webpage

Tags: websites

Probably my question may seem frivolous, but it's important for me.

**Can somebody recognize the webpage that is described below?**

A very nice Ubuntu webpage appeared few months ago. It was a one big slidable page with multiple sections and layers.

As I was scrolling  down the backgrounds were changing and some other pictures were sliding too (as they were floating) but slower than the background slid.

I've made a lot of Google search but they've been futile.

**So I am looking for this webpage and I hope somebody could recognize it by my description.**

Comment: Do you look for the features to implement them in your own homepage? If so I suggest the following website: http://html5demos.com/

Comment: Yes I do, thank you, it is a very useful link. However I also would like to get some inspiration from the webpage that I am looking for.

Comment: A colleague of mine has made a complete presentation in html5 - It works very simple and you do not need damn powerpoint,just a browser.And making the slides available is fairly easy, just offer it on your webserver ;)

Comment: The word you're looking for is `parallax`. Just do a search for `parallax effect css`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably talking about:

http://thenewubuntu.com/

an advertisement site built by the OMG! Ubuntu! team.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am really quite grateful! Finally my seeking ended.